# Doppler effect vectors

Tags: acoustics, doppler-effect

Trying to get to a formula with vectors for the doppler effect.

$f_r (c+(v(x_r,t) - v(x_s,t))\cdot v(x_r,t)||v(x_r,t)||^{-1})= f_s (c+(v(x_s,t)- v(x_r,t))\cdot v(x_s,t)||v(x_s,t)||^{-1})$

I am not sure this formula is correct because wikipedia talks about velocity relative medium. I am fairly confident I got all the sign convention stuff automatically by using the dot product of the velocity vectors though, unless it should have been the magnitude of the difference vectors multiplied by the sign of their dot product... see, the just words formula is hard to understand for me. Is the medium velocity group velocity or phase velocity or something else? Been a while since I did acoustics and am not sure of what "c" of a medium is. Please tell me how to augment the formula.

Update:
The velocities should be projected onto position differences not velocity differences it has been explained below. Not sure about c.

Answer (score 1):

The speed $c$ is the speed of the wave relative to the medium which for sound is usually air which is not moving relative to the ground.
In the diagram below if the velocities of the source and the receiver relative to the ground are $\vec v_{\rm s}$ and $\vec v_{\rm r}$ then the appropriate velocities are the components of $\vec v_{\rm s}$ and $\vec v_{\rm r}$ along the line joining the source to the receiver which are shown in red on the diagram.

[image]

Comment: Still not sure how the correct formula should be but have the upvote at least.